# SU retagging: [mail], [apple-mail], [mail.app]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The various email tags caught my attention and I started looking to see if the **[mail]** tag can be gotten rid of.  It seems to have a few uses:

1. generic stand-in for **[email]** or **[mail-server]**;
2. specific-name tag for Mail.app / Apple Mail / Mail, the default OS X email client; this usage also has tags **[apple-mail]** and **[mail.app]**;
3. (well, i thought there was a snailmail question in there somewhere, but i'm missing it...)

Here's the tag links and numbers we're looking at:

- [**[email]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email) (557)
- [**[mail-server]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mail-server) (8)
- [**[mail]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mail) (65)
- [**[mail.app]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mail.app) (67)
- [**[apple-mail]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apple-mail) (10)

What I need to know:

1. It seems obvious to me that **[mail.app]** and **[apple-mail]** are the same thing and should be merged.  I think **[apple-mail]** may be clearer.  What does the community think?
2. The **[mail]** tag should be eliminated, but that's a 2-part job:

   1. First, someone needs to go through the list manually to retag **[mail]** to **[apple-mail]** or **[mail.app]** on those questions it's appropriate to.  Start with the searches [**[mail]+[osx]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mail+osx) and [**[mail]+[mac]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mail+mac).

      Another pass might be desirable to get questions that should be tagged **[mail-server]**, if any.  (I'm uncertain whether this tag is necessary; it isn't widely used.)
   2. Once that's done, the remaining **[mail]** tag can be merged into **[email]**.

Thoughts?  Opinions?  ...Volunteers?

Comment: @jon: why did you remove the [tags] tag?  this was a request for discussion about specific tags used on superuser, in addition to being a [retag-request].

Comment: @quack: This question is kind of a hybrid of a discussion about tags and a retag request (much more so the latter, IMO). I think it's clear enough with `[discussion]` + `[retag-request]`, but if you want to roll back, that would be okay.

Answer (score 2):

#### [apple-mail]

*[company-product]* is a popular convention, and seems to work well.  However, people tend to avoid it for wide swaths of Microsofts product line, perhaps unnecessarily so.  MSFT tends to use very generic names that could be useful in other contexts; e.g. [windows], [sql-server]. Compare [google-chrome] to [chrome] (meaning a UI aspect).

Go with [apple-mail]; [apple-mail.app] could work, but is probably too long.  However, I'm not a Mac user to judge which fits in better between the two.

Comment: i think [mail.app] is sufficient to specify the thing clearly, but i tend to agree with you that [apple-mail] fits our conventions better.  unfortunately the product's name is simply "Mail", so none of them are particularly "wrong".  :(